# How to import sql developer connections-file in 0xDBE

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, datagrip

Trying the 0xDBE from jetbrains. Does anybody know how I can import my old Oracle SQL Developer's connection file?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer exports connections in XML. I do not believe that Datagrip has a connection importer which can be configured to ready the connections structure for SQL Developer at the moment.

To make things a little easier you can use the TNS entries housed in SQL Developer's `app/client/product/....` path and load those into Datagrip.

Answer (score 0):

You can try DataGrip plugin ["sqldeveloper connections importer"](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13103-sqldeveloper-connections-importer)

Also follow [a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-328) in our bug tracker.